# Custom button within buefy notification

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, buefy

```
this.$buefy.notification.open({
  duration: 3000, 
  message: message + `<br><a @click="forgotPassword">Forgot password?</a>`, 
  position: 'is-bottom-right',
  type: 'is-danger',
  hasIcon: true,
  icon: 'alert-circle'
})
```

How to make buefy notification custom HTML button working?

Comment: Why not use a modal?

Comment: Why would I want to recreate notification functionality with modal for this?

Comment: Because if you're trying to use a notification for clicking, you're recreating modal functionality with notification